# Return certain values from String ArrayList

Tags: java, string, parsing, arraylist

I have declared `List<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>();`

It's outputs look like this:

```
[0.0,100.0,5.0],[1.0,200.0,8.0],[2.0,600.0,2.0],....
```

So for example, by calling `listOFvalues.get(0)` I would access `0.0,100.0,5.0`

What I'm trying to do is, access and store its column values. 
So basically I need store `0.0,1.0,2.0` as the first array/arrayList, `100.0,200.0,600.0` as the 2nd and so on.

The problem is, so far, I'm only able to get the whole Row (with `listOfValues.get()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the String method [Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to make an array from each String element.

```
List<String> splittedArray = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s: listOfValues)
{
  for(String ss: s.split(",")) splittedArray.add(ss);
}
```

Then you can access each element through `splittedArray`.

Another option is to store the splitted elements into a matrix so they can be accessed as columns:

```
List<List<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s: listOfValues)
{
  matrix.add(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
}
```

Comment: With System.out.println(splittedArray.get(2)); I get the 3rd value only of the first Row, how can i make a for loop that goes through all columns?

Comment: @user3086819 If you chose to dump your elements to a matrix: `for(List<String> row: matrix) { for(String element: row) { System.out.print(element+"\t"); } System.out.println(""); }` If, on the other hand, you decided to use a plain array (`splittedArray` in my example): for(String element: splittedArray) System.out.println(element);

Comment: With the matrix option i see as output all rows & columns of listOfValues(need to store/save these columns somewhere) , and with the splittedArray i get the first row shown up vertically.

Comment: @user3086819 The code I posted to print the splittedArray will show you all your elements in one row, just an example of how you can access them. Both options contain already all the elements, I mean they are already stored "somewhere". If you want to access the second column of the first row of the matrix: `matrix.get(0).get(1)`. splittedArray contains all your elements in one single row/column (as you would like to think about it).

Comment: The .get().get() made it! kudos

Answer (score 1):

You could create your List extending ArrayList and overwriting the get method:

```
public class ColumnArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<String> {
    public String get(int i) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        String delim = "";
        for(int j=0;j<super.size();j++) {
            buffer.append(delim).append(super.get(j).split(",")[i]);
            delim = ",";
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

To see it working:

```
public class Demo {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfValues = new ColumnArrayList<String>();
        listOfValues.add("0.0,100.0,5.0");
        listOfValues.add("1.0,200.0,8.0");
        listOfValues.add("2.0,600.0,2.0");
        System.out.println(listOfValues.get(0));
        System.out.println(listOfValues.get(1));
        System.out.println(listOfValues.get(2));
    }
}
```

Will print what you want:

```
0.0,1.0,2.0
100.0,200.0,600.0  
5.0,8.0,2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **String** class method `split()`.

```
String temp="0.0,100.0,5.0";
String[] array=temp.split(",");
```